# CSS media query conflict

Tags: html, css, printing, overriding

I am having an issue with `@media print {}` query.
I am trying to make my portfolio look good in print. The link is: http://izzatnadiri.com/

When I try to print the page, the content is shifted to the right. The reason for that is following the code:

```css
@media (min-width:768px) {
  #wrapper { padding-left: 400px; }
  #sidebar-wrapper { width: 400px; } 
}
```

Here is the link to that CSS file //izzatnadiri.com/css/simple-sidebar.css

This code should be overridden by print.css when printing. The code is below:

```css
@media print{
  #sidebar-wrapper {width: 0px;}
  #wrapper {padding-left: 0px !important; -webkit-transition: none !important; }
}
```

Here is the link to print.css  //izzatnadiri.com/css/print.css

However, when I try to print the page, the print query does not override the min-width query.

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/print.css">` below all the other css links in your head.

Comment: Thanks for response, Adam. I did that, but that didnt fix the issue :/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting "screen" on your first media query? I mean like this :

```css
@media screen (min-width:768px) {
  #wrapper { 
    padding-left: 400px; 
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper { 
    width: 400px; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hey there, yes I have. That didnt fix it though.